# how to get a node field value in a html.tpl.php template file?

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a field in a node type called `body_styles`.

I need to modify html.tpl.php to get the value of `body_styles` to add it to the classes of the body tag.

I tried with `dpm($node->content['body_styles']['#value']);` but I get nothing. I think it is because $node is not available in html.tpl.php.

how do I get a node field value in a html.tpl.php template file?

**@svetlio: almost done**:

The class is correctly added to $variables['classes_array'] but if I inspect the body (see my capture below the code) tag is not there

```
    function omega_subtheme_2_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        global $language;
        $node = entity_load_unchanged('node', arg(1));

        dpm($node -> field_body_class['und'][0]['value']);

        if (isset($node -> field_body_class['und'][0]['value']) && $node -> field_body_class['und'][0]['value']){
            $variables['classes_array'][] = $node -> field_body_class['und'][0]['value'];
            dpm($variables['classes_array']);
        }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: I clear all cache several times, not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way - without edit template and adding code in template.php

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $node = entity_load_unchanged('node', arg(1));

      if (isset($node -> field_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value']) && $node -> field_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value']) {
        $variables['classes_array'][] = $node -> field_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value'];
      }
    }
  }
```

replace THEME with your theme_name and FIELD_NAME with your field_name, clear the cache

edit: I change "$node = entity_load('node', arg(1));" to $node = "entity_load_unchanged('node', arg(1));"

Comment: I use friendly url and it is a multilingual site then the urls has appended the Path prefix (en, es, fr). then the function get the arguments in a wrong way: arg(1) and arg(0)

Comment: add "global $language;" before "$node = entity_load_unchanged('node', arg(1));" and replace all 'und' with "$language -> language" without the quotes

Comment: almost there. I need to leave 'und' to get it to work. The class is correctly added to $variables['classes_array'] but if I inspect the body tag is not there. Please see the function at the bottom of my question.

Comment: must to clear cache after each change in template.php before refreshing page, maybe twice

Comment: I clear all cache several times, not working...

Comment: omega is more specific theme, I don't know it well, but in her readme.txt in preprocess folder have "Any custom preprocess functionality can (rather than directly in template.php) be placed 
in this preprocess folder in a file named as such:

TEMPLATE_preprocess_html() = preprocess-html.inc", so try to move this function following the theme instructions

Comment: A couple of notes of caution: as it stands, this preprocess function will require a node to be loaded twice on every full node view; also I believe it's better to use [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) rather than accessing the field directly.

Comment: I read the doc for preprocess function with omega. You are right, it is different. I can't get it working though, but this out the scope of this question